# WebAdministration powershell integration with log4net

Tags: iis-7.5, log4net, powershell-4.0

im looking for a way to integrate log4net configuration into iis so i can have the ability to:

- Check from a powershell script using Import-Module WebAdministration that a site is properly configured.
- Check if the log4net xml is correct (Following a xsd or some reference)
- (Optional) Configure it for a site from the IIS->Site->Management->Configuration Editor

The idea is to have a way of validating the log4net configuration section (in the web.config or in a separate file) so we can detect bad configurations or configurations that doen´st follow our standards.

I been trying to add the log4net to the configSchemas of iis server, but i don´t have a proper definition of the xml to follow. Right now i´m looking for the best way to validate site configurations using powershell so if you have a better idea of how to do it, it´ll be very welcome

Thanks,

Comment: There's a log4net xsd [here](http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd) - it notes however: "Please be aware that though this xsd attempts to cover most of the usages you 
will encounter with log4net configurations it is by no means complete.  The 
primary reason (excuse) for this is that the xml format used by log4net config 
files does not conform to any real standard.  This is both it's primary 
weakness and it's strength."

Comment: OK So there is no standard for it. do you know if i can use this xsd inside the FX_schema.xml of iis? is iis capable of reading xsd? i found that exact link yesterday but i couldn´t incorporate it to the iis directly. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I don't know how, but [this](http://mvolo.com/iisschemaexe-a-tool-to-register-iis7-configuration-sections/) looks relevant

Comment: I check that one out, but it is more of a automated tool to register an existing xml, doesn´t seem to support xsd. I created a simple xml to be load and added to the iis and i can read the xml from powershell now and configure it from iis manager, but it is very limited. i´ll try to translate that xsd to the xml that iis is expecting. Thanks again